# Implement the following method to sort the rows in a twodimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, return, 2d

I have been working on this problem all day and cannot find out what to do next. I have it sorting the rows but it will not sort the last row completely. Here is my code.I know once I or someone gets this I will feel stupid .Thank you

```
    public class Sort2DRow
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      int[][] matrix = {{3,5,6}, {4,1,2},{9,8,7}};

      System.out.println("Before the sort");
      for(int row = 0; row <matrix.length; row++){
         for(int col = 0; col <matrix[row].length; col++){
            System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }

      System.out.println();//Spacer
      System.out.println("After sort method");
      sortRow(matrix);

   }

   public static int[][] sortRow(int[][] m)
   {
      int temp = 0;
      for(int row = 0; row < m.length ; row++)
      {
         for(int col = 0; col < m.length -1; col++){
            if(m[row][col] > m[row][col + 1])
            {
               temp = m[row][col];
               m[row][col] = m[row][col + 1];
               m[row][col + 1] = temp;
            }
         }
       }

       for(int row = 0; row <m.length; row++){
         for(int col = 0; col <m[row].length; col++){
            System.out.print(m[row][col] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }

       int[][] result = m;
       return result;
   }

}
```

Comment: You have two loops that loop on `col`.  They do not have the same upper bound, and I suspect one is just a typo.  However, I don't know if this is enough to fix the problem (since this particular matrix is square, the error might not actually make a difference).

Comment: OK, I think you're just not using a valid sort algorithm.  You're sorting each row indepdently, right?  But the algorithm that you use to sort each row is a single `for` loop that goes through the row, and there's no way you can sort an array with a single pass through the array.  If this is an Exchange Sort or Bubble Sort, you'll need to study exactly how an Exchange Sort works.  You'll need a nested `for` loop (and the loop on `row` doesn't count).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but the problem is that you're mistakenly assuming that `for(int row = 0; row < m.length ; row++)` is your outer bubblesort loop. It's actually just the loop that "loads" the next row in the 2-d array. So you'll need to add the missing loop:

```
for(int col = 0; col < m[row].length; col++){ //This is the real outer bubblesort loop. Change it to m[row].length
    for(int nextCol = col; nextCol < m[row].length; nextCol++) {
        if(m[row][col] > m[row][nextCol])
        {
           temp = //I'll let you figure this out
           m[row][col] = //....
           m[row][nextCol] = //...
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help! It now works perfectly. I'll post the code for anyone who needs this method

Answer (score 0):

The final code product

```
public class Sort2DRowTest
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      int[][] matrix = {{3,5,6}, {4,1,2},{9,8,7}};

      System.out.println("Before the sort");
      for(int row = 0; row <matrix.length; row++){
         for(int col = 0; col <matrix[row].length; col++){
            System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }

      System.out.println();//Spacer
      System.out.println("Sort method");
      sortRow(matrix);

      System.out.println();//Spacer
      System.out.println("After the sort");
      for(int row = 0; row <matrix.length; row++){
         for(int col = 0; col <matrix[row].length; col++){
            System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }

   }

   public static int[][] sortRow(int[][] m)
   {

      int[][] result = new int[m.length][m[0].length];

    // Copy from m to result
       for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
         for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++)
        result[i][j] = m[i][j];

      int temp = 0;
      for(int row = 0; row < result.length ; row++)
      {
         for(int col = 0; col < result[row].length; col++){ //This is the real outer bubblesort loop. Change it to m[row].length
            for(int nextCol = col; nextCol < result[row].length; nextCol++) {
               if(result[row][col] > result[row][nextCol])
               {
                  temp = result[row][col];
                  result[row][col] = result[row][nextCol];
                  result[row][nextCol] = temp;
               }
            }
            System.out.print(result[row][col] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
       }
       //int[][] result = m;
       return result;
   }

}
```